# Configure my app to stop it to rewriting URLs?

Tags: angular, url-rewriting, routes, adal.js

I'm developing an Angular 6 App and I need to get fragments from callback when I call Microsoft login endpoint.

I have a service with a function called login:

```
login() {
    const redirectUrl = window.location.origin + '/redirect/auth/bot';
    const authUrl = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?client_id='
                        + this.clientId + '&response_type=id_token+code&redirect_uri='
                        + redirectUrl + '&state=147852369&nonce=678910&response_mode=fragment&prompt=consent&scope='
                        + 'openid email https://graph.microsoft.com';
    window.location.href = authUrl;
}
```

I added a route on my **route.module.ts** like this:

```
{
  path: 'redirect/auth/bot',
  component: BotAuthorizationComponent
}
```

the redirectURL from Microsoft contains the fragment needed (example: `localhost:8080/redirect/auth/bot#code=toto&id_token=blabla`)
But when my app is redirected to this route, the app is rewriting it with `localhost:8080/redirect/auth/bot`before loading component. So I lose my fragment and can't get it from `ActivatedRoute`.

I **can't** use **adal-js** due to the fact we are using multiple client Ids.
I tried to use `PathLocationStrategy`/`HashLocationStrategy`, differents options on my routeModule( `useHash:true/false` , `initialNavigation:"disabled"`), use `resolver` and `interceptor`.
I tried with differents browsers, webservers and I still have the issue.

It works with angular 2. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: two questions: 1) is it your auth url that is redirecting and dropping it? 2) have you tried using the built in angular router instead of modifying window.location directly?

Comment: Hi,  1) My redirect url from microsoft is rewrite by my app when it  redirects to the route from my `route.module.ts`
2) using the built in angular router change nothing.